# Tikz, scope scaled, and shared node

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

In order to include a small sub-figure in my main figure, I tried to use scaled scope. However, when I try to refer to a node out of the scaled scope, the node pointed is at the position of the old non-scaled node... Here is a picture :

[image]

Do you know how to avoid that ?

Thank you !

PS : Here is my WME.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}     
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,matrix,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=1},overlay]
      \node[fill=green]   (a) {A};
      \node[fill=green,right=of a] (b) {B};
    \end{scope}
    \node[draw,below=5mm of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[<->] (c) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \hspace{3cm}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=0.2},overlay]
      \node[fill=green]   (a) {A};
      \node[fill=green,right=of a] (b) {B};
    \end{scope}
    \node[draw,below=5mm of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[<->] (c) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: pgf manual extract: _Canvas transformations should be used with great care. In most circumstances you do not want line widths to change in a picture as this creates visual inconsistency. Just as important, when you use canvas transformations pgf loses track of positions of nodes and of picture sizes since it does not take the effect of canvas transformations into account when it computes coordinates of nodes (do not, however, rely on this; it may change in the future)._

Comment: @PaulGaborit : So what is the good way to proceed ? Tikzpicture ? Savebox ? Other things ?

Comment: Try `scale=.5` instead of `transform canvas={scale=.5}`.

Comment: Nothing happened with "scale=0.5"...

Comment: None of your nodes use numeric coordinates. However, the `scale` option applies only to numeric coordinates.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Maybe the OP wants the nodes to be scaled? That was how I understood the idea. `transform canvas` will do that, but `scale` alone will not. So I think, possibly, `transform shape` is what might be wanted here. At least, so I guessed. I could well be wrong.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Yes, but I can be willing to scale even I don't hardcode position.

Comment: @cfr: It does nothing either.

Comment: @tobiasBora But you said it was exactly what you wanted below ;).

Comment: @cfr: Yes, but the "every node/.append style" was usefull, what I tried before was only to replace transform canvas with transform shape ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want this?

[image: scaled and unscaled]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=green]   (a) {A};
    \node[fill=green,right=of a] (b) {B};
    \node[draw,below=5mm of b] (c) {C};
    \draw[<->] (c) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \hspace{3cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.2, every node/.append style={transform shape}]
      \node [fill=green]   (a) {A};
      \node [fill=green,right=of a] (b) {B};
    \end{scope}
    \node [draw,below=5mm of b] (c) {C};
    \draw [<->] (c) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```